# How to find the best subset from an array whose sum is equal to X number in php

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations

I have an array as

```
$array = array(3,5,6,10,15,30);
$sum = 69;
```

then there are 3 different sums that equal 69:

```
3+5+6+10+15+30,
3+6+10+20+30,
3+6+30+30,
```

The best one is 3+6+30+30. Because it contains higher number from array to complete the sum that reduce the number count.

(A number can be used within a sum as many times as it appears in the list, and a single number counts as a sum.)
Here is the code that I am implementing

```
$sum = 18;
$list = array();
$this->sumUpRecursive(array(3,5,6,10,15,30), $list);  //function call
$list = array_filter($list,function($var) use ($sum) { return(array_sum($var) == $sum);});
var_dump($list);

function sumUpRecursive($array, &$list, $temp = array()) {
      if (count($temp) > 0 && !in_array($temp, $list))
        $list[] = $temp;
      for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
        $copy = $array;
        $elem = array_splice($copy, $i, 1);
        if (sizeof($copy) > 0) {
          $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
          sort($add);
          $this->sumUpRecursive($copy, $list, $add);
        }
        else {
          $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
          sort($add);
          if (!in_array($temp, $list)) {
            $list[] = $add;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Result:

```
Array
    (
[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 10
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 15
    )
```

)

I hope this might be bit complex . Its taking a number from array once. But how to figure out for 69...

Thanks

Comment: You say *A number can be used within a sum as many times as it appears in the list, and a single number counts as a sum.* but then you have one sum where you have 30 two times but it only occurs once in the initial array. So you got me confused :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  The best one might be 3+6+30+30, but what rules are you incorporating to get there?  Because you've been combining them with no apparent rules, coming up with a '20' and another '30'.  By that logic, I'd say that `69` is the best one. ;)

Comment: It is a [binary knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem. DP will solve it.

Comment: This actually sounds like the [Bin-Packing-Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). So what have you tried so far?

Comment: A binary knapsack problem would involve weights to the values, but the entirety of the array is the sum provided, so nothing needs to be left out in order to achieve the desired capacity.

Comment: May be, it could be binary knapsack problem or bin-packing problem. I am not aware of that. Can anybody help me to write the php code for that. I need to figure out the problem..Thanks

Comment: If you want people to write the code for you, you do not want to figure out the problem. You want someone to solve it for you. I would try to explain it in more detail, ask a real question that can be answered in such a way that you can figure out how to write the code that does what you want to accomplish. Algorithms won't teach you anything if you don't take the time to figure them out.

Comment: @inquam:- not exactly that. I did it by myself with recursion but not able to figure out.

Comment: Then present us with your solution to show us your thought process. There is nothing saying that recursion wouldn't have been the choice of any of us here. Recursion is actually often used in a lot of algorithms since it makes the solution sleeker (but perhaps not optimized for efficiency).

Comment: I have added my code for thought process

Comment: Is this question still active here? If yes: 1. *number can be used within a sum as many times as it appears in the list* But in your example solution: `3+6+30+30` You have 30 twice, but it's only 1 time in the array. So do you can use a number of the array as many as you want or not? 2. Is the order of the result important? e.g. `3+6+30+30` or `30+30+3+6` has it to be from low to high or just the correct numbers?

Comment: 3. What should it return when it can't build the sum? Should it return 0 or should it return how far it got e.g. `$arr = [3, 4]; $sum = 8;` Should it here return `0` or `4+3` ? 4. What should it do when it get stuck e.g. `$arr = [3, 5, 6]; $sum = 8;` Now here it would start with 6, but then it can't build the sum to the end, but 5+3 would work? What should it do?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

What does this code do (the function `getKnapsackSum()`)?

1. prepare data

In the first few lines of the function I prepare the data, that means I sort the array DESC with [`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php). I get the last element of the list with [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php), reset the array pointer with [`rest()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and assign it to a temp variable.

2. input check

Before I begin to calculate the sum I check that the input isn't 0.

3. calculate the sum

After this the real stuff happens (IT voodoo, not really)! I start with a loop which is false as long as I didn't got the sum. The next 2 lines in the while loop are there to check, that first if the sum can't be calculated, that it returns an array with a 0 and second that when we got a "offset" of the array pointer, that I set it back the last array element.

Then the first if clause is there to check if it made a mistake and it has to try it with lower values. So as an example:

```
list = [3, 5, 6]
sum = 8
```

```
                        //entire sum
                        | 0
                        |
check 6:                |
                        |
      6 + sum  -> 8     | 6               | fits
      6 + sum  -> 8     |                 | does not fit
                        |
check 5:                |
                        |
      5 + sum  -> 8     |                 | does not fit
                        |
check 3:                |
                        |
      3 + sum  -> 8     |                 | does not fit

--------------------------------------------------------
                          = sum = [6] != 8
```

As you can see right here with this example the algorithm made a mistake, because it started to build the sum with 6, but after this it couldn't build it until the end, now here is where the first if clause checks, if the current element of the array pointer is the end of the array and this value + the current sum is higher than the goal.

If this is the case it deletes the last value from the sum array and pops off the highest element of the list. So now it tries it again with the following data:

```
list = [3, 5]
          //^ As you can see it removed the highest value of the list 
sum = 8
```

```
                        //entire sum
                        | 0 <- it removed the last value of the sum array, here 6
                        |
check 5:                |
                        |
      5 + sum  -> 8     | 5               | fits
      5 + sum  -> 8     |                 | does not fit
                        |
check 3:                |
                        |
      3 + sum  -> 8     | 3               | fits
      3 + sum  -> 8     |                 | does not fit

--------------------------------------------------------
                          = sum = [5, 3] == 8
```

So as you can see now the first if clause made it possible to build the sum with the list. So the if statement makes sure that it corrects errors of level 1.

Now the second if statement in my while loop corrects errors of level 2. So what are errors of level 2? We also look again at an example:

```
list = [3, 5, 6]
sum = 22
```

```
                        //entire sum
                        | 0
                        |
check 6:                |
                        |
      6 + sum  -> 22    | 6               | fits
      6 + sum  -> 22    | 6               | fits
      6 + sum  -> 22    | 6               | fits
      6 + sum  -> 22    |                 | does not fit
                        |
check 5:                |
                        |
      5 + sum  -> 22    |                 | does not fit
                        |
check 3:                |
                        |
      3 + sum  -> 22    | 3               | fits
      3 + sum  -> 22    |                 | does not fit

--------------------------------------------------------
                          = sum = [6, 6, 6, 3] != 22
```

So as you can see it couldn't build the sum entirely. But this time it isn't an error of level 1, because if we take the last element away from the current sum and go through the new list where we removed the highest element it still can't build the sum as you can see here:

correction of errors level 1:

```
list = [3, 5]
          //^ As you can see it removed the highest value of the list 
sum = 22
```

```
                        //entire sum
                        | [6, 6, 6] <- it removed the last value of the sum array, here 3
                        |
check 5:                |
                        |
      5 + sum  -> 22    |                | does not fit
                        |
check 3:                |
                        |
      3 + sum  -> 22    | 3              | fits
      3 + sum  -> 22    |                | does not fit
                        |
--------------------------------------------------------
                          = sum = [6, 6, 6, 3] != 22
```

So as you can see it is stuck now, it can't correct the mistake only with the first if clause. And here is where the second if statement checks if the list is empty, if this is the case that means that you tried every value, but the mistake is higher up in the sum array.

So now it goes back 1 array element of the sum array and deletes it. It also takes the mistake as offset to get a list without the number which was the mistake. So here: `[6, 6, 6, 3]` the 3 gets removed from the first if clause so now the array looks like this: `[6, 6, 6]`. Now the second if statement see's that the mistake was 6. It removes it and also corrects the list where it chooses the numbers from.

So now the result array looks like: `[6, 6]` and the list to choose numbers from like this: `[5, 3]`. And now that it made a correction of level 2 it can build the sum as you can see here:

```
list = [3, 5]
          //^ As you can see it removed the highest value of the list 
sum = 22
```

```
                        //entire sum
                        | [6, 6] <- it removed the last value of the sum array, here 3 and 6
                        |
check 5:                |
                        |
      5 + sum  -> 22    | 5              | fits
      5 + sum  -> 22    | 5              | fits
      5 + sum  -> 22    |                | does not fit
                        |
check 3:                |
                        |
      3 + sum  -> 22    |                | does not fit
                        |
                        |
--------------------------------------------------------
                          = sum = [6, 6, 5, 5] == 22
```

So after this the if else statement is there just to check if the current value of the list fits into the sum array and isn't bigger than the goal. If it fits it adds it to the array otherwise it goes to the next list element.

Now as you can see my code corrects a few errors, but I'm not 100% sure that it works for everything and I'm also not sure if you can produce errors of level 3 where you have to go back in the sum array an correct 3 values, and if there is one I'm also not sure if my code corrects it or maybe even fall into a endless loop.

But after all this talking here is the code which does all the magic:

```
<?php

    //data
    $arr = [3,5,6,10,15,30];
    $sum = 69;


    //get sum
    function getKnapsackSum($arr, $sum) {
        //prepare data
        rsort($arr);
        $end = end($arr);
        reset($arr);
        $tmp = $arr;
        $result = [];

        //check if it is not a empty input
        if($sum == 0 || empty($tmp) || array_sum($tmp) == 0) return [0];

        //calculate the sum
        while(array_sum($result) != $sum) {
            if(empty($tmp) && empty($result)) return [0];
            if(current($tmp) === FALSE) end($tmp);

            //correction for errors level 1
            if(current($tmp) == $end && array_sum($result) + current($tmp) > $sum) {
                array_pop($result);
                array_shift($tmp);
                reset($tmp);
            }

            //correction for errors level 2
            if(empty($tmp)) {
                $mistake = array_pop($result);
                if($mistake == NULL) return [0];
                $tmp = array_slice($arr, array_search($mistake, $arr)+1);
                reset($tmp);
            }

            if(array_sum($result) + current($tmp) <= $sum)
                $result[] = current($tmp);
            else
                next($tmp);     
        }
        return $result;
    }


    $result = getKnapsackSum($arr, $sum);
    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 30 [2] => 6 [3] => 3 )
```

Also here a few examples of inputs and there outputs from my code:

```
    input        |        output    
------------------------------------
 list: []        |
 goal:  0        |  sum: [0]
------------------------------------
 list: []        |
 goal:  1        |  sum: [0]
------------------------------------
 list: [0]       |
 goal:  1        |  sum: [0]
------------------------------------
 list: [0]       |
 goal:  0        |  sum: [0]
------------------------------------
 list: [3, 5, 6] |  //error level 1
 goal:  8        |  sum: [5, 3]
------------------------------------
 list: [3, 5, 6] |  //error level 2
 goal: 22        |  sum: [6, 6, 5, 5]
------------------------------------
 list: [5, 7, 9] |  //can't build the sum
 goal: 56        |  sum: [0]
------------------------------------
 list: [5, 7, 9] |
 goal: 34        |  sum: [9, 9, 9, 7]
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi @Rizier123, unfortunately I am quite sure that your function indeed does not work for level three errors. When I try to achieve 2850 with ```[500,330,300,250,180]``` it does not work. However, when I remove the leading 500 from the array, it does work. (outcome: 7 * 330 + 3 * 180). Would you perhaps like to push me in some direction to improve your function? I've tried but the amount of additional ifs makes your function significantly less clean.